# how to hide url using .htaccess after myproject in http://localhost/myproject-name/admin/home/

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to hide everything from URL using `.htaccess` after `myproject-name` in this URL `http://localhost/myproject-name/admin/home/`

My .htaccess is

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproject-name/$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to hide  after `myproject-name` in my localhost url at `http://localhost/myproject-name/admin/home/`

after i publish my application in hosting it is there any thing to change

Comment: Do you have an issue? Does rewrite not work? Please add a question and details about what is happening.

Comment: Salim, the common cause of the problem you've described is that `.htaccess` files are disabled by the Apache configuration. If you have access to the Apache configuration make sure that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` for your www-root.

Here is an article that describe what I mean: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-set-up-enable-htaccess-apache

Comment: I tried but I didn't succeed. Can you give me an example of that?